# Tooltip for button

Tags: c++, winapi

I use function from MSDN [Create a Tooltip for a Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298368%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

```
HWND CreateToolTip(int toolID, HINSTANCE hInst, HWND hDlg, PTSTR pszText) {
    if (!toolID || !hDlg || !pszText) {
        return FALSE;
    }

HWND hwndTool = GetDlgItem(hDlg, toolID);

HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
    WS_POPUP |TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
    hDlg, NULL,
    hInst, NULL);

if (!hwndTool || !hwndTip) {
    return (HWND)NULL;
}

TOOLINFO toolInfo;
toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
toolInfo.hwnd = hDlg;
toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hwndTool;
toolInfo.lpszText = pszText;
SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo);

return hwndTip;
}
```

Then in `WndProc` `WM_CREATE` I create button `Button=CreateWindowEx(
            0,
            L"BUTTON",
            L"My Button",
            WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD,
            10, 10, 100, 24, 
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)ID_TOOLTIP,
            hInst,
            NULL);`

Finally create tooltip `tooltip_mess = CreateToolTip(ID_TOOLTIP, hInst, hWnd, (PTSTR)"Tooltip message");`
But it doesn't work, I can't see my tooltip, where I did wrong?

Comment: Are you activating the tooltip by sending it a `TTM_ACTIVATE` message?

Comment: SendMessage(tooltip_mess,TTM_ACTIVATE,TRUE,0); but same result

Comment: What I need write in WM_NOTIFY?

Comment: Don't cast the tooltip text into a PTSTR, use the TEXT macro instead (i.e. TEXT("Tooltip message"). Note if you prefer you can also use the _T macro. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/12/71851.aspx for more information.

Comment: You are not using the exact same code that the MSDN articles shows. Are you checking if `CreateToolTip()` returns NULL? `TTM_ADDTOOL` returns whether it succeeds or fails, so you should update `CreateToolTip()` to check for that, and have it destroy the tooltip and return NULL if `TTM_ADDTOOL` fails. `(PTSTR)"Tooltip message"` is wrong, considering that you use L"BUTTON" on `CreateWindowEx()`, which means `UNICODE` must be defined, so you need to use L"Tooltip message" (or `TEXT("Tooltip message")`) instead. You are typecasting a `char*` to a `wchar_t*`, which is wrong.

Comment: If using the TEXT macro solve the problem check the return value when you send the TTM_ADDTOOL message. Also are you checking the return value from CreateToolTip?

Comment: fix this mistakes,text is sent correctly to the function

Comment: have you add the correct manifest and set the correct _WINNT_ version.

Comment: #pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
HWND CreateToolTip(int toolID, HWND hDlg, HINSTANCE hInst, PTSTR pszText)
{
    if (!toolID || !hDlg || !pszText)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    // Get the window of the tool.
    HWND hwndTool = GetDlgItem(hDlg, toolID);
    if (!hwndTool)
    {
        return NULL;
    }                              

    // Create the tooltip. g_hInst is the global instance handle.
    HWND hwndTip = CreateWindowEx(NULL, TOOLTIPS_CLASS, NULL,
                              WS_POPUP |TTS_ALWAYSTIP | TTS_BALLOON,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                              hDlg, NULL, 
                              hInst, NULL);

   if (!hwndTip)
   {
       return NULL;
   }                              

    // Associate the tooltip with the tool.
    TOOLINFO toolInfo = { 0 };
    toolInfo.cbSize = sizeof(toolInfo);
    toolInfo.hwnd = hDlg;
    toolInfo.uFlags = TTF_IDISHWND | TTF_SUBCLASS;
    toolInfo.uId = (UINT_PTR)hwndTool;
    toolInfo.lpszText = pszText;
    if (!SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo))
    {
        DestroyWindow(hwndTip);
        return NULL;
    }

    return hwndTip;
}
```

```
case WM_CREATE:
{
    Button = CreateWindowEx( 0, L"BUTTON", L"My Button", WS_VISIBLE|WS_CHILD, 10, 10, 100, 24, hWnd, (HMENU)ID_TOOLTIP, hInst, NULL); 

    tooltip_mess = CreateToolTip(ID_TOOLTIP, hWnd, hInst, L"Tooltip message");

    break;
}
```

```
if (tooltip_mess)
    SendMessage(tooltip_mess, TTM_ACTIVATE, TRUE, 0);
```

```
if (tooltip_mess)
    SendMessage(tooltip_mess, TTM_ACTIVATE, FALSE, 0);
```

Comment: tryed this code but written tooltip_mess = CreateToolTip(ID_TOOLTIP, hInst, hWnd, L"Tooltip message"); without hInst, if I am right function receive only 3 parameters. Unfortunately I can't see tooltip. Where need write "if"?

Comment: I updated my answer. As for the `if` statements, you put them wherever you need them, when you need to show/hide the tooptip on the button.

Comment: if (!SendMessage(hwndTip, TTM_ADDTOOL, 0, (LPARAM)&toolInfo)) always DestroyWindow it's normal? I want to do something like toolbar, when mouse on button ->shows tooltip. I try show tooltips when I clicked on the button, but get error that "The variable 'tooltip_mess' is being used without being initialized."

Comment: `TTM_ADDTOOL` returns TRUE if successful and FALSE otherwise, so your tooltip is obviously not being added to the button correctly. As for the initialization error, that sounds like you are not managing your `tooltip_mess` variable correctly.  Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) demonstrating what you are really doing.